# Text to Speech is not working in the activity (android)

Tags: android, multithreading, api, android-activity, text-to-speech

I am developing an activity that reads the balance for the user. When the user enter the Balance activity it should read the balance immediately. But that's not working for me here is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_balance);
EditText editTextTotalBalance= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBalanceNow);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

myTTS=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status)
        {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) 
              {
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
              }
        }
    });
        }

    }).start();

// take the string from the edit text to read the balance 

String   speech=editTextTotalBalance.getText().toString();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  {
        ttsGreater21(speech);
  } 
else {
        ttsUnder20(speech);
    } 
}// end of onCreate method

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void ttsUnder20(final String speech) {

Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
            }
            catch(Exception excep){

            }
        }
    };
    mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
}

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void ttsGreater21(final String speech) {
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
    String utteranceId=this.hashCode() + "";
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
            }
            catch(Exception excep){

            }
        }
    };
    mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
}
public void onPause(){
    if(myTTS !=null){
        myTTS.stop();
        myTTS.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Also, it shows me an error says Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. for that I add many thread in my code. 
Also, I check for the API version because when I implemented it regularly I found there are some SmartPhones are not working well for the speech and it let the app crushed.

Thank you looking forward for your help,

Comment: The TTS engine isn't ready to speak until the `onInit()` method is called with `SUCCESS` return code. You need to either wait until `onInit()` is run or redesign your application so that some other class owns a `TextToSpeech` instance that's always available.

Comment: how to make sure that onInit() is success ? Or how to redesign my application ?